# Low fps on some Android devices

Tags: android, opengl-es, gpu, cocos2d-x, tegra

I have been poting a game for Android devices which i created on iOS using cocos2d x.
I'm getting pretty nice fps around 45 on iPad2.
When it comes to Android device fps varies as mentioned below:

1. **Device -** Samsung note    **GPU -** Mali-400MP  **FPS -**  55-60
2. **Device -** Moto defy+      **GPU -**        PowerVR SGX530  **FPS -** 35-40
3. **Device -** Samsung Google Nexus S   **GPU -** PowerVR SGX540 **FPS -**  50-55
4. **Device -** Moto xoom              **GPU -**  ULP GeForce   **FPS -**   15-20
5. **Device -** Samsung galaxy 10.1    **GPU -**  ULP GeForce   **FPS -**   15-20

I am using PVR (RGBA4444) art resources. Is FPS drop issue related to the GPU used by the device. 
Or Somebody can help with getting good fps on moto-xoom and samsung galaxy 10.1 device(atleast 40-45).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the GPU for these devices are very different. They have different strategies and tricks for optimization. For Nvidia Tegra2 devices download "Tegra Android Toolkit 1.0r4" from here http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-resources and try some of nice performance measurment tools like oprofile, perfhud, tegra-profiler. They can help you determine where is bottleneck in your app.

Read also [OpenGL ES 2.0 Development for the Tegra Platform](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/tegra/docs/tegra_gles2_development.pdf) document for hints about optimizing your OpenGL ES 2.0 code.

Comment: hi, Thanks for your reply. I m using opengl es 1.1 as cocos2d-x supports that only.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding this line to your Application.mk:

> APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a

If ARMv7 instruction set is available on device usage of those will give you some performance boost.